# I'm working on udemy clone and how can I change list using onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I was trying to clone Udemy website and I don't understand how can I make dropdown menu like Udemy category have. So how can I create like this? There is a image given below of the Udemy website:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to build it from scratch, for the purposes of learning, or do you want some ready-made code? There would surely be some JavaScript menu libraries out there. I wonder though whether it could be done with CSS these days.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i'm creating udemy website from scratch for my project .but i stucked in .as i was trying to copy udemy drown down menu .i'm not  getting understand how to implement this with dynamic data or static data?